# .update() ContentProvider throws Unknown Uri, even though .query() works?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

App **A** with the following `AndroidManifest.xml` content (name and authority redacted)

```
<provider
     android:name="test.provider"
     android:authorities="test.content_authority"
     android:exported="true" />
```

With the following ContentProvider class:

```
public class Provider extends ContentProvider {
    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, 
                      String[] selectionArgs) { 
        // [...]
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, 
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

From another App **B** I have no problem querying this provider:

```java
String URL = "content://test.content_authority/data";
Uri data = Uri.parse(URL);
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(data, null, null, null, null);
```

But when I try to `update` an entry:

```java
String URL = "content://test.content_authority/data";
Uri favarticles = Uri.parse(URL);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("key", "value");
getContentResolver().update(favarticles, values, null, null);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown Uri: content://test.content_authority/data
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:169)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:560)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1316)
    at com.example.test_contentprovider.MainActivity.updateEntryTest(MainActivity.java:119)
```

Is there anything obviously wrong? Do I not have the rights to access the Provider? Why do I get an `Unknown Uri` Exception when I can access this URI with a `query`?

thank you very much.

Comment: I think you URL is incorrect.

Comment: How can the URI be incorrect when the query works?